# setTimeout not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

My setTimeout seems to be working for logging in, but not for submitting data. :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajaxSetup({async:false});

function Validate_submit(form) {
    var Address1_input = form.address1.value;
    var Address2_input = form.address2.value;
    var City_input = form.city.value;
    var State_input = form.state.value;


    $.post('../scripts/submit_check.php', {address1php: Address1_input, address2php: Address2_input, cityphp: City_input, statephp: State_input}, 
    function(output) {
            $('#submit_msg').html(output).fadeIn(500);
            if (output == 'Submitting...') {
        var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function () {location.reload();}, 1000);
            } else {
                $('#submit_msg').html('something went wrong').fadeIn(500);
            }
        }
        );

}
```

The same code works in my log-in popup window:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({async:false}); 

function Validate_login(form) {
    var Email_input = form.email.value;
    var Password_input = form.password.value;
    var Rememberme_input = form.remember_me.checked;

    $.post('../scripts/login_check.php', { emailphp: Email_input, passwordphp: Password_input, rememberphp: Rememberme_input},
        function(output) {
            $('#login_msg').html(output).fadeIn(500);
            if (output == 'Logging in...') {

                var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function () {location.reload();}, 1000);
            }
        }
        );  
}
```

When I click the submit button in the submit form, it shows 'Submitting...' for a split second, but not for the whole second (like in the login-popup). Can someone help me?

Comment: You may want to know that `async: false` for ajax has been deprecated from the latest version of jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably need to cancel the actual `<form>`'s submission. `return false` from the `onsubmit` handler after you call `Validate_submit`.

Comment: @wanovak: Given the function definition, I would assume that this is an `onsubmit` attribute and so `e` isn't available. (Restructuring would be a good idea, of course.)